# in Extjs 3.3, How to add another button near by the 'select file' button?

Tags: extjs, append

My problem is: I need to support `select local image files` and also `preview server side images`, I am using an plugin `FileUploadField`. It has a
button for select from local files, how to add another button near it ?

perhaps this is the same question :

How to find a buttons's parent component, and append another child (button)?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your custom button after field is rendered like this

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var fp = new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField({
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
        emptyText: 'Select an image',
        listeners : {
            afterrender : function(fupload) {
                this.customButton = new Ext.Button({
                    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
                    cls: 'x-form-file-btn',
                    text : 'some button'
                });
                this.customButton.el.insertAfter(fupload.fileInput);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Example:

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/DD2Jv/)